# javascript or jquery to change list class into andother class name after hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I wan't to use jquery or javascript to change the `<li class="cat">` dynamicly when hovering over the cat list to `<li class="cat show">` also i am using joomla so that i take the noConflict function into consideration

```
<ul> 
  <li class="cat"> <a class="rt" href="" aria-haspopup="true">Motors</a>
    <div class="sub" role="menu"> 
      <ul class="col"> 
        <li class="title">Top categories</li> 
        <li class="icn"> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Cars</a></li>
        <li class="icn"> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Motorcycles</a></li> 
        <li class="icn"> <a href="" aria-haspopup="false">Parts</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</ul>
```

please help me out :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? also please fix your html markup, it is missing some closing tags

Comment: Usually askers give it a go first and then show here what they've done so far

Comment: Refer This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825967/how-do-i-dynamically-add-or-remove-classes-attached-to-an-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok first of all you should at least try to find it on your own,
second try this:

```
jQuery(".cat").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJmBS/

Comment: did you even see my jsfiddle link?

Comment: perfect didnt expect that to work, its charming now, and guess what it didnt conflict with my other joomla and now all site loading as i really want, you saved me alot of time thank you so much, cheers

Comment: i have one question to you, after i take off the hovering the class dont go back to its original class, can you tell me what are the code to have it back after hover is off ?

Comment: You can try to use mouseout or mouseleave on the li's or on the ul

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's on hover function, see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

First you select the tags you want to be triggered by your hover function.

The first parameter of the hover function is the handlerIn (what happens when mouse enters), and the second function parameter is the handlerOut (when mouse leaves again).

When mouse enters, add the class "show", but when it leaves again, remove that class.

```
$("li.cat").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("show");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("show");
  }
);
```

Does this ansswer your question?

Comment: how to make the code to return the value back after its off the hover